# Why does my code uncomment this part of the code out

Tags: c, string, escaping

So I've been making a simple HTTP flooder with a Wget and a user agent but when flooding i realize this happens

```
125.27.78.172 - - [26/Apr/2016:12:38:45 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4961 "-" "Wget"
```

And if you are confused about this error i asked my friend to flood my VPS and this happend

```
208.67.1.176 - - [26/Apr/2016:12:48:32 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 4961 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.85 Safari/537.36"
```

Why is is it not working with me code:

```
sprintf(command, "wget -O /tmp/fff --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.85 Safari/537.36" http://208.67.1.176/ ");
```

if you're wondering how this is a flooder the main code loops it

Comment: Don't you need to escape those `"`s in `sprintf()`?

Comment: This `sprintf()` will not compile.

Comment: You don't want to be writing the output anyway, you should redirect it to `/dev/null`: `wget -O /dev/null ....`

Comment: Its working now and yes with the whole code i have it compiles fine

Comment: and Kuba in my code i have this:     strcat(command," >/dev/null");

Comment: Then your code is not the code you show. As it stands the `sprintf(..)` stuff won't compile.

Comment: i will not be showing be showing the whole code as its a private code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the string?

```
sprintf(command, "wget -O /tmp/fff --header=\"Accept: text/html\" --user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.85 Safari/537.36\" http://208.67.1.176/ ");
```